# Do bonuses from proficiency and Fighting Style stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, proficiency, fighting-style

One of the pregen fighters in the Starter Set has proficiency in simple & martial weapons, giving a +2 bonus, but also has the *Archery* fighting style, giving a +2 bonus.

I don't see these added together.  Why bother adding 'Archery' if a +2 bonus is already added in proficiencies; does the Archery option offer anything later on?

Answer (score 27):

Both of those modifiers *do* add to the attack roll; the combined modifier is then relevant ability mod (DEX, +3) + proficiency bonus (+2) + Archery bonus (+2), yielding the +7 you see in the "Attacks & Spellcasting" section of the pregen character sheet (available from Wizards [here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/character_sheets)).

[image: pregen ftr (version 2) from starter set]

(Note that the +4 attack bonus for greatsword is just the relevant ability mod (STR, +2) + proficiency bonus (+2).)

Answer (score 8):

A character's Proficiency Bonus and the Fighter's *Fighting Style* class feature do stack.

Proficiency with something in 5e allows you to add your *Proficiency Bonus* to the relevant rolls. This is a dynamic bonus that scales with character level (not class level) and caps at +6 at level 20.

Archery is a static +2 bonus to attack rolls made with ranged weapons granted when you choose this feature. Also note that *Fighting Style* is not a class feature unique to the Fighter.