# Is a D&D 5e Starter Set Pregenerated Character's Attack Bonus Wrong?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-sheets

I have the starter set and I am wondering if a pregenerated character's attack bonus is wrong.

The character is the Human Fighter with the Folk Hero background.

The attack bonus for the Greatsword is +4: +2 from STR and +2 from proficiency, so this seems correct.

The attack bonus for the Longbow is printed as +7, but I only see +3 from DEX and +2 from proficiency. Am I missing something?

There are a couple of others that seem to be off as well.

Comment: [Related] [Do Weapon Proficiency and Fighting Style stack?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65482)

Comment: Still... I didn't ask about stacking. I answered my own question. The question marked as a duplicate, may relate to my question, but is not exactly the same. I pretty much asked where the stacking came from. The character sheet provided didn't state so. The update to my question regarding the duplicate answered this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is no longer marked a duplicate of the stacking question. (I mentioned it as "related" because it is, but it's not a duplicate of it.) It is a duplicate of the "attack bonuses seem wrong" question though, so it's been marked as such. No worries though: it's not a bad thing at all. We like duplicates, because they provide another wording that points toward the answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Two seconds later, I figured it out:

Fighting style = Archery - Gain a +2 bonus.

Sorry for wasting space, but hopefully it will help others.

Comment: Looking over the answer to the question marked as duplicate has a screenshot of the character sheet in question. However the one I have from the set doesn't included the definition of the fighting style, which states that the +2 was added. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Interesting. I took my screenshot from the [Starter Set Characters](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/StarterSet_Characters.pdf) .pdf downloaded from wizards.com. I don't have the printed version that came with the boxed set with me to compare--are those the ones you had at hand?

Comment: Mine where the actual hard copies in the box. How would I attach an image.

Comment: This FAQ should help: [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491)